# Xcode Table Cell not Fully Highlighted

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a tableview with a header view on it and paging enabled:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
CGRect headerFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:headerFrame];
header.backgroundColor = [UIColor flatWhiteColor];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header;
self.tableView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

The Cells are the height of the screen:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
}
```

however, when I run it on my iPhone 6, the first table cell is never highlighted properly:

[when its not highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgRZ0.jpg)

[when I select the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrufo.jpg)

help anyone?

Comment: Everything seems well the non selected part (as it seems to be) is actually the Header View ..

Comment: Actually when i tap the so called "extra part" of the header, the cell still highlights.

Comment: can you try remove the header View I guess you will figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer. It turns out a UIView inside my header was a bit too long and overlapped into my table cell. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the height of headerView it's not actually equal with the size of the tableView and on the next page(the first table cell) you are seeing a part from the headerView.

Try this code:

```
CGRect headerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height);
```

and

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     return self.tableView.frame.size.height;
}
```